# Does Amazon API Gateway support endpoint URL with port numbers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I tried using Amazon API Gateway and tested it on an endpoint URL. It works fine if the server is listening on port 80.

However, if I give the endpoint URL with a different port, (say http://52.xxx.xxx.33:8080) it gives an error. If I visit this URL directly on a browser(GET method), it gives me the required output.

Is this a feature that is not available yet in AWS API Gateway?

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The supported endpoint port ranges has changed since this question was asked.  Amazon AWS API Gateway now supports endpoint ports `80`, `443` and `[1024, 65535]`.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I can't find a reference in their documentation.

Comment: I worked on the product.  I'm following up internally to get this added to the official documentation.

Comment: @BryceThomas Any updates on this? I still do not see this feature.

Comment: @AronRotteveel the documentation has been updated here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html

Answer (score 3):

Having worked with AWS for the better part of 11 years, and API Gateway since the day of its release, I am unaware of any way to configure it to listen on any port other than 443. If Bryce could cite his source it would be extremely helpful, as this lack of support has been a major pain point (and deal-breaker in almost every case I have experienced) with the implementation of API Gateway.

From the AWS API Gateway FAQ (emphasis mine):

> **Q: Can I create HTTPS endpoints?**
>
> Yes, all of the APIs created with Amazon API Gateway **expose HTTPS
>   endpoints only**. Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP)
>   endpoints. By default, Amazon API Gateway assigns an internal domain
>   to the API that automatically uses the Amazon API Gateway certificate.
>   When configuring your APIs to run under a custom domain name, you can
>   provide your own certificate for the domain.

Comment: OP was asking about including a port in the *integration endpoint* URL.  The documentation you quote refers to the URL of *your API Gateway API* only being exposed over HTTPS.  In other words, you can only hit API Gateway over HTTPS, although API Gateway can hit your backend over HTTP.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, there must have been conversation via PM. I still can't gather that intent from the wording of the question, as it seems the issue was not being able to address the endpoint with the port the server is listening on.

Comment: (Apologies for digging up an old question - the issue of being unable to listen on non-standard ports without significant additional infrastructure has been a pain point for a long time, so I'm always on the lookout for new ways to handle it.)